# Python convert date type to %Y-%m-%d

Tags: python, flask

I got a date in format like this: `Wed, 15 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT` i need to make it to `%Y-%m-%d` something like `2020-07-15`
So, in test3 variable data is `Wed, 15 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT`
I try something like this

```
date_time = test3.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", test3)

writing `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I have imported

```
from datetime import datetime
```

So any ideas on how to convert it?

Comment: this is the syntax `datetime.strftime(test3, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: test3 its just variable, data is from Json if u need code its something like test3=data[3]   ```date_object = datetime.strftime(test3, "%Y-%m-%d")``` dont work for me, getting ```TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

test3 = "Wed, 15 Jul 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
date_time = datetime.strptime(test3, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(date_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_str='Wed, 15 Jul 2020 00:00:00'
dt=datetime.strptime(time_str,'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: i try, but i got error like this   ```raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  GMT```